# What spells can be used to damage a Rakshasa before L7 slots are available?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, spell-resistance

I've been looking for the most effective ways to damage a Rakshasa as a spellcaster, before L7 slots become available. After reading the 3 questions below,

1. [Is a Rakshasa immune to Animate Objects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94004/is-a-rakshasa-immune-to-animate-objects/94006#94006)
2. [Can Maximilian's Earthen Grasp or Bigby's Hand target a Rakshasa?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94007/can-maximilians-earthen-grasp-or-bigbys-hand-target-a-rakshasa)
3. [Does a Mundane Arrow Fired From a Magical Bow Count as a Magical Weapon Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57839/does-a-mundane-arrow-fired-from-a-magical-bow-count-as-a-magical-weapon-attack)

I'm wondering if the following spells will work:

1. Magic Weapon: Per the last question, my reading is that a Wizard could cast this on a crossbow (or bow, if they have proficiency), and deal semi-decent damage (assuming they are good aligned, it would target the R's vulnerability).
2. Alter Self (Natural Weapons, Piercing): Similar idea, available to other classes, though would require going into melee (not so problematic due to damage, but due to Curse).
3. Elemental Weapon: Similar idea, though I'm not sure if the bonus elemental damage applies.
4. Shillelagh: Doesn't target the R's vulnerability, but a Druid could go this route if desperate for damage.

Are there other (better?) ways for casters to damage this sucker before L7 slots are available?

Note: I'm aware that buffing/assisting is another way to contribute to the fight--I'm interested specifically in offensive options available.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Other than summoning spells, you don't have a lot of options

**The rakshasa will be immune to damage from all of the spells you mentioned above.** Jeremy Crawford [has addressed](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/932792921333493760) several of these spells:

> Q: Hi Jeremy, does a Rakshasa's 'Limited Magic Immunity' protect it from weapons enhanced by shillelagh or the magic weapon spell since they are spell effects?
>
> A: Shillelagh and magic weapon are spells. Limited Magic Immunity prevents a rakshasa from being affected by spells of 6th level or lower, unless it wishes to be.

As *elemental weapon* is a similar weapon enhancing spell, I have every reason to believe that the ruling would be similar on it.

As far as *Alter Self* goes, the damage you could do (and the fact that the damage is magical) are parts of the effects of the spell. And:

> The rakshasa can’t be affected or detected by spells of 6th level or lower unless it wishes to be. (MM, p. 257 post errata)

**The fact that summoned creatures can still damage the Rakshasa was also [explicitly spelled out by Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1009573805415489537)** and justified thusly:

> A rakshasa's Limited Magic Immunity offers no protection against a summoned creature. The creature's presence is a spell effect. The creature itself is not a spell effect.

In all of the spells you mentioned, the damage done is itself a spell effect. So the Rakshasa will be immune to these effects.

Since the Rakshasa has immunity to "bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from non-magical attacks", one of the only ways to injure a Rakshasa with a spell of 6th level (or lower) when it does not wish to be damaged is by summoning a creature that can do some other form of damage. An example would be casting *Conjure Elemental* (a 5th level spell) and summoning a Fire Elemental. This Elemental's attacks would do fire damage, to which the Rakshasa is not immune.

Comment: Yeah, I get *shillelagh*, but I find it really hard to understand the JC ruling on *magic weapon*. Paraphrasing the quote about summoned creatures – the change in nature of the weapon is the spell effect, your (now magical +1) weapon and it's damage are not part of the spell's effects.

Comment: Buffs on *creatures* seem like they should work fine. Honestly, Jeremy Crawford’s tweet about magic on weapons doesn’t make a whole lot of sense to me, either.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the magic weapon ruling here? You seem to think it makes sense and I think it would pay to explain the kind of logic you see in it. Or if you don't think it makes sense to call that out.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose It would seem that Crawford lost the plot on that one

Answer (score 3):

### Magical Effects that Aren’t Spells

> Are there other (better?) ways for casters to damage this sucker before L7 slots are available?

I actually had a Paladin in such a predicament recently.

A Paladin’s *Divine Smite* power is a way to expend spell slots to damage a foe, but it is not a spell. Thus it can damage a Rakshasa.

Mike Mearls tweeted to this effect about [Divine Smite and Rakshasas](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/05/27/if-i-use-divine-smite-on-a-rakshasa-who-has-limited-spell-immunity-does-he-take-any-damage/).

(This is the only power that comes to mind that would work like this.)

### Spells the Help Indirectly

As others have mentions lower-level spells can only cause a Rakshasa harm indirectly.

You could charm or dominate a creatue and get it to attack the Rakshasa.

Another spell that could be useful is *Enhance Ability: Bull’s Strength*. This could give a character advantage on grappling — Strength *(Athletics)* — checks, which could conceivably help the character force the Rakshasa into a trap or over a ledge.