# Does "resistance to damage from spells" reduce damage caused by summoning spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, summoning, spell-resistance

A few creatures, such as the [Archmage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/archmage), have resistance to damage from spells.

If I cast a summoning spell such as [Conjure Animals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-animals), do the summoned creatures do half damage against an enemy that has resistance to damage from spells?

It's not clear to me if a summoned creature's damage is considered to originate from the summoning spell, or from the creature itself, which is not a spell.

Comment: Not quite the same, but maybe a hint: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73349/do-objects-affected-by-the-animate-objects-spell-count-as-magical-weapons-for-th

Comment: Related as well: "[Do attacks from creatures summoned by the Conjure Animals spell count as magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129160)"

Comment: Counter example: Imagine that some cleric resurrected your dead swordsman PC. If an Archmage become resistant to all the damage done by your swordsman, it would feel pretty weird, right?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### No

The spell *Conjure Animals* doesn't deal any damage, since no damage is mentioned in the text. Thus, the damage dealt by any creatures summoned by the spell comes from the creature, not the spell.