# Is the damage from Conjure Volley magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Conjure Volley is a 5th level Ranger spell:

> You fire a piece of **non magical** ammunition from a ranged weapon or throw a non magical weapon into the air and choose a point within range. Hundreds of duplicates of the ammunition or weapon fall in a volley from above and then disappear.

If you use magic to duplicate non-magical ammunition, can the result damage a Werewolf for example?

Comment: Related: [Are spells that do piercing, bludgeoning, or slashing damage considered magical damage?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59362/23064) possibly duplicate?

Comment: @daze413, the answer there only talks about non-weapon spells, but Conjure Volley is specifically mentioning weapons.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes. *Conjure Volley* will damage lycanthropes.

Here's the relevant part of the *Conjure Volley* spell description:

> A creature takes 8d8 damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. The damage type is the same as that of the ammunition or weapon.

### The weapons don't do the damage, the spell does.

Here are the immunities for a werewolf (SRD, p. 331):

> **Damage Immunities** bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks not made with silvered weapons.

*Conjure Volley* isn't a 'nonmagical attack'. It's [not an attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71245/what-counts-as-an-attack) of any kind: it's a spell that does damage.

Contrast with a black pudding, which is just immune to slashing damage. *Conjure Volley* using (say) handaxes would do zero damage to a black pudding, but full damage to a werewolf.

Comment: You could say that a Saving Throw is different from an Attack because a Saving Throw represents an attempt to resist or avoid. Or, the way I always think about it and explain it: "Attacks are for you trying to hit them, Saves are for them trying to get the hell out of the way of your Fireball."

Answer (score 4):

#### Conjure Volley deals magical damage

In a [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/630915981016064000)<sup>1</sup>, Jeremy Crawford clarified (emphasis added):

> Regardless of damage type, the **direct damage** of a spell is magical.

Reading the text of *Conjure Volley* we see the following:

> A creature takes 8d8 damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

Thus, we can tell that the spell itself is the direct source of the damage. The spell uses the same wording for damage as *Fireball*, *Maximilian's Earthen Grasp* or *Blade Barrier*, and those spells are all distinctly magical, as they all directly cause damage.

#### But what about spells like *Animate Objects* or *Enlarge/Reduce*?

The spell effects for these examples are not the direct source of the damage that may result from using these spells, so they are not necessarily magical. In the cases of the above spells, the damage is indirectly caused by the attack actions of the animate objects, or through the attack actions of an enlarged creature.

However, *Conjure Volley* does not indirectly cause damage. The spell itself directly causes damage, because the text of the spell says that it causes damage, the amount of which depends on a saving throw. Thus, because it is direct damage from a spell, the damage must be magical.

---

1. As of the release of the [2019 Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), Jeremy Crawford's tweets are no longer official rulings. However, they remain excellent sources for "rules-as-intended" analysis, since he is still the lead rules developer.

Answer (score -2):

### No... unless you used a silvered arrow.

Relevant parts of the spell:

> You fire a piece of nonmagical ammunition from a
>   ranged weapon or throw a nonmagical weapon into
>   the air and choose a point within range.
>
> The damage type is the same as that of the ammunition or weapon.

This is very, very clear. You use non-magical ammo, and the damage dealt is the same as the ammunition used. Which means it's non-magical.

There's also precedence that just because magic creates the damage source, it doesn't mean the damage is automatically magical. For example, Create Undead makes minions for you, but their attacks do not count as magical unless their stat block specifically state that they do.

Here's a comparable spell that takes a mundane weapon and makes it magical:

**Shillelagh, PHB pg. 275 (emphasis mine);**

> The wood of a club or quarterstaff you are holding is
>   imbued with nature’s power. For the duration, you can
>   use your spellcasting ability instead of Strength for
>   the attack and damage rolls of melee attacks using
>   that weapon, and the weapon's damage die becomes
>   a d8. **The weapon also becomes magical, if it isn’t
>   already.** The spell ends if you cast it again or if you let go
>   of the weapon.

This is how you know if your spell counts as magical. It will explicitly state it in the description. If it doesn't, the damage type is NOT magical by default. *Conjure Volley* and *Conjure Barrage* lack this statement, so their damage type is NOT magical in nature.

Here's an example of a spell that creates ammo for you that is not magical:

**Swift Quiver, PHB pg. 279-280 (emphasis mine):**

> You transmute your quiver so it produces an endless
>   **supply of nonmagical ammunition**, which seems to leap
>   into your hand when you reach for it.

Comment: "Damage type" is defined on p. 196 of the PHB. There's nothing about magical vs. nonmagical there, just the named damage types such as bludgeoning, piercing and slashing. Conjure Volley cast using a spear is a spell that does 8d6 piercing damage. The weapon doesn't do the damage.

Comment: I might be inclined to agree, but it specifically states the damage type is the same as the type of ammunition being used. That's very specific wording.

Comment: Based on the wording of lycanthropic damage immunity, would you say that  Conjure Volley would damage them? If you could directly connect that to your interpretation of the spell, that would clarify things.

Comment: That's what the No is there for. It's a direct answer to the question asked. Unless of course he Conjure Volley a silvered arrow.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli, the damage type IS the same if it is piercing for an arrow. Magical or non-magical is not part of the damage type, because there is no such damage type as "magical piercing".

Comment: Yes, I know that. In fact, I'm fairly certain I made that abundantly clear through the use of examples, such as Shillelagh, which clearly specify it has now become a magical weapon. Conjure spells don't do that.