# How do I refer to non-spell attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, terminology

What is the proper way to refer to non-spell attacks in D&D 5e? "Non-spell" attacks doesn't seem right.

I'm looking for a term that includes attacks made with a melee weapon, a ranged weapon, an improvised weapon, and unarmed strikes.

Comment: If you share with us more about the context, the answers will be more likely to be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to describe them mechanically (according to the rules) or in-fiction (narratively describing it to players/characters in the story)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### "Weapon Attacks"

Attacks that are not "spell attacks" are necessarily "weapon attacks".

Even attacks that aren't made with a weapon can be weapon attacks.

As an example, the vampire's Unarmed Strike action on [page 353 of the SRD](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) ([direct PDF](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf)) is listed as a "Melee Weapon Attack".

#### Sage Advice

Jeremy Crawford, lead rules designer of Dungeons & Dragons, confirmed on Twitter that ["every attack is either a weapon attack or a spell attack."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/951903089564336128)

Comment: Except for the attacks that are neither spell nor weapon (e.g. unarmed attacks, claw attacks, shove etc.)

Comment: unarmed is an attack with a natural weapon instead of with a tool. still a weapon attack, claws, teeth. fist. etc.

Comment: Unarmed attacks are melee weapon attacks made with a non-weapon.

Comment: Also, there are two exceptions to this: shoves and grapples. Both are described in the rules as "special melee attacks". Besides such exceptions, though, the answer is correct.

Answer (score 12):

All the given examples are considered 'weapon attacks'.

Even unarmed strikes are considered melee weapon attacks; see the following quote from the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf):

> Some attacks count as a melee or ranged weapon attack even if a weapon isn’t involved, as specified in the text of those attacks. For example, an unarmed strike counts as a melee weapon attack, even though the attacker’s body isn’t considered a weapon.

Ultimately, there are (currently) only two types of attacks: spell attacks and weapon attacks. Everything that isn't a spell attack is a weapon attack, and vice versa.

> If I understand it correctly, there are weapon attacks and there are spell attacks and that covers all attacks. So if an attack isn't one, it's the other.
>
> [@MadDuckie, 12 Jan 2018](https://twitter.com/MadDuckie/status/951902193669455872)
>
> This is correct: every attack is either a weapon attack or a spell attack. #DnD
>
> [@JeremyECrawford, 12 Jan 2018](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/951903089564336128)