# Does Wand of the War Mage bonus apply to spells like GFB and Booming Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, attack

Does Wand of the War Mage bonus apply to spells like [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade) and [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade)?

I could make an argument for this either way.  On the one hand, these spells "Make a melee attack with a weapon" which makes me think that it would not.  On the other hand, from an action standpoint, it is clearly a spell and not an attack.  Has this been settled?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wand of the War Mage does not affect these spells.

"Spell attacks" and "weapon attacks" are mutually exclusive attack types (All attacks are one or the other, not both; [See also](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/115618/15614)), and the attacks made as part of these spells are melee weapon attacks; they use your normal attack stats/bonuses rather than your spell attack stats/bonuses, etc.

As such, effects that benefit spell attacks have no impact on the attacks for these spells.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I was starting from a place of assuming there was something preventing stacking a +X WoWM and a +X weapon for a single attack roll.  Now I know how to explain it to my bladesinger that has both!