# Is there a cantrip or spell that grants resistance to damage from natural attacks in the way Blade Ward does for weapon damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-resistance

The spell [*blade ward*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blade-ward) (PHB, p. 219) has the following effect:

> Until the end of your next turn, you have resistance against bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage dealt by weapon attacks.

Is there a cantrip or spell similar to this that works against natural attacks or non-weapon damage such as claw, bite, tail, or slam attacks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to know if there's a cantrip in the 5e published rule set that gives resistance to damage from natural weapons, (such as claw, bite, tail or slam attacks) similar to how Blade Ward functions?

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115616/37154).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Blade ward already works for natural attacks**

It may not seem obvious, but Blade Ward already does this. A claw or bite attack (etc) are classed as Melee *Weapon* Attacks.

This can be seen if you look at any monster description, where under Actions it will typically say something like:

> **Claw**. *Melee Weapon Attack*: +6 to hit, reach 5ft, one target. Hit: 6 (1d6+3) piercing damage

Blade Ward will not protect you against other forms of damage such as that caused by spells or by falling (which is bludgeoning damage but not *weapon* damage).

Comment: What about unarmed attacks?

Comment: @DoktorJ, I think that should fall under the same category as weapons as well. As clarified by PJRZ Claw is described as a melee weapon attack, then unarmed  should be the same dealing bludgeoning damage.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver indeed it does. I first found on [Roll 20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Combat#h-Melee%20Attacks) where it noted "none of which count as weapons", but the [Unarmed Strike](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Unarmed%20Strike#h-Unarmed%20Strike) link indeed lists Unarmed Strike as a "simple weapon". Not sure how "canonical" Roll 20 is, but it's a reasonable reference I think.

Comment: All attacks are either spell attacks or weapon attacks. Source: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/28/if-i-understand-it-correctly-there-are-weapon-attacks-and-there-are-spell-attacks/

Comment: @DoktorJ: Roll20 isn't really a reliable rules source. Unarmed strikes were removed from the weapons list in a PHB errata and the basic rules were correspondingly updated, but [the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks) do state: "Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons)."

Comment: And Crawford has clarified that ["An unarmed strike is a nonweapon \[you can't silver a fist\] that can make a melee weapon attack."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/666339794331414529)